# Extracting numbers from a url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var exampleURL = '/example/url/345234/test/';
var numbersOnly = [?]
```

The `/url/` and `/test` portions of the path will always be the same.

Note that I need the numbers between `/url/` and `/test`. In the example URL above, the placeholder word example might be numbers too from time to time but in that case it shouldn't be matched. Only the numbers between `/url/` and `/test`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var exampleURL = '/example/url/345234/test/';

// this will remove all non-numbers
var numbers = exampleURL.replace(/[\D]/g, '');

// or you can split the string and take only that 3rd bit
var numbers = exampleURL.split(/\//)[3];

// or match with a regex
var numbers = exampleURL.match(/\/(\d+)\/test\//)[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines:

```
var result;
result = value.match(/\/url\/([0-9]+)\/test/);
// use result[1] to get the numbers (the first capture group)
```

That relies on the `/url/` and `/test` bits, since you said they were reliable. More generally, this will match the *first* run of digits in the string:

```
var result;
result = value.match(/[0-9]+/);
// use result[0] (not result[1]), which is the total match
```

The [MDC page on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions) is pretty useful.

Note: Instead of `[0-9]` above, you can use `\d` which stands for "digit". I don't because my regex-fu is weak and I can never remember it (and when I do, I can never remember whether it's all digits or all non-digits [which is `\D` -- you see my confusion]. I find `[0-9]` really clear when I read it later. Others may find `\d` clearer, but for me, I like the explicit-ness of listing the range.

Answer (score 1):

regex that would work is

```
matches = exampleURL.match('/\/.+\/url/([0-9]+)\/test\//');
```

I think that's right.